# Electron-Builder installing wrong prebuild for native dependency (serialport)

Tags: electron-builder, node-serialport

I've been trying to integrate the serialport npm module into an electron application. I have it imported into my main process and have kept it as an external in my webpack configuration. I'm using the following:

- Node 13.2.0
- serialport 9.0.0
- electron 9.0.5
- electron-builder 22.7.0

From my package.json:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "electron .",
    "build": "npm-run-all --parallel build:main build:renderer",
    "build:main": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.main.js --mode production",
    "build:renderer": "webpack --config ./webpack.config.renderer.js --mode production",
    "pack": "npm run-script build && electron-builder --dir",
    "dist": "npm run-script build && electron-builder"
  },
  "repository": "https://github.com/electron/electron-quick-start",
  "build": {
    "appId": "my_app",
    "files": [
      "build/**/*",
      "node_modules/**/*"
    ]
  },
```

My Problem is that when I run my "dist" script electron-builder uses what I think is the wrong chrome target. Here is the output:

```
• build native dependency from sources  name=@serialport/bindings
                                          version=9.0.0
                                          platform=win32
                                          arch=x64
                                          reason=prebuild-install failed with error (run with env DEBUG=electron-builder to get more information)
                                          error=prebuild-install info begin Prebuild-install version 5.3.4
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries enforced with --force!
    prebuild-install WARN install prebuilt binaries may be out of date!
    prebuild-install info looking for cached prebuild @ C:\Users\Me\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_prebuilds\90024b-bindings-v9.0.0-electron-v80-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http request GET https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/releases/download/@serialport/bindings@9.0.0/bindings-v9.0.0-electron-v80-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install http 404 https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/releases/download/@serialport/bindings@9.0.0/bindings-v9.0.0-electron-v80-win32-x64.tar.gz
    prebuild-install WARN install No prebuilt binaries found (target=9.0.5 runtime=electron arch=x64 libc= platform=win32)
```

I have yet to try and manually install the prebuilt binary into that local cache location. However, I do not know how or why electron-builder is looking for the v80 build which does not exist. The electron version 9.0.0 uses v83 for the target according to [their releases](https://github.com/electron/releases), and serialport also has a v83 build [here](https://github.com/serialport/node-serialport/releases). Is there something wrong with my setup or version configuration that I'm missing here? How is electron-builder making that decision?

Other things I've tried:

- "npmRebuild = false" build flag: results in an error in the executable.
- electron-rebuild: not recommended by electron-builder